# How can I restore Network Indicator in Unity Panel?

Tags: indicator, panel

I just cleaned up junk files on my Ubuntu 12.04. After that, I restarted my Ubuntu. But then, I lose the network indicator in the Unity panel. I don't know how to restore the network icon as before.

Comment: I know that this posting is a little old, but has anyone come up with a solution that actually work? I also tried `gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/panel` and `rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel`, but this also did not work.

Answer (score 4):

It can be reinstalled!

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following commands one by one:

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

Restart your system for the change to take effect.

That's it!

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: thank you very much Basharat. This works for me . I am using ubuntu 14.04. I try lot of things. But did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solved my problem on Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
```

Answer (score 0):

The below command worked for me without installing any extra packages.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet
```