# Network Manager Icon disappeared 14.04

Tags: unity, wireless, networking, network-manager, indicator

So a couple of weeks ago my network manager icon stopped appearing; I still get automatically connected to my saved networks and the internet works fine, etc. If I go into System Settings and look at the Network settings I can still see all the networks, only the icon that's normal in the top bar is missing.

I have no idea what caused this, I don't remember installing anything. I think it just happened after a regular update.

I tried these commands to make sure I was properly up-to-date, (which I found on another forum post):

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That didn't do it so I found this post: [Network manager indicator missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159812/network-manager-indicator-missing) and
I followed the instructions in those answers:

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome && \
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

And, quoted from an answer there:

> Add `nm-applet` to the Startup Applications (which may be found by
>   entering "Startup Applications" in the Dash).

I restarted and then saw no Unity interface at all! So I tried those 3 commands above to update again and thankfully that fixed Unity but I still don't have my network manager.

If I try the command `nm-applet` in a terminal it says:

```
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
```

So.... I'm pretty much stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This has been an extremely annoying issue and, although I see a handful of other occurrences reported around the net, no one seems to have a good solution. I'm on the verge of doing a clean reinstall of Ubuntu over this. That's a lot of my time to backup what I need, reinstall, and then reinstall all of the apps and packages I use. Is there no way to repair this issue?

Comment: These two might help:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/364219/network-connection-icon-has-disappeared-from-the-panel-in-ubuntu-13-10

http://askubuntu.com/questions/138196/how-can-i-restore-network-indicator-in-unity-panel

Comment: I did a `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome`, and after `killall nm-applet; nm-applet &` the icon came back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to fix it by changing `nm-applet` to launch with `dbus-launch nm-applet`. To see if this will work for you, try running `dbus-launch nm-applet` and see if that shows up properly. To make the fix permanent, I edited `/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop` and changed

```
Exec=nm-applet
```

to

```
Exec=dbus-launch nm-applet
```

Comment: Unrelated, but my battery indicator actually ended up disappearing too... no idea why. But, because of these issues and wanting to make my Ubuntu partition much bigger, I reinstalled. (I almost never use Windows on my laptop anymore :) )

I am accepting this answer in case in helps anyone in the future, but note, I never got the chance to try it.

Comment: If this is not working Try adding the dbus-launch nm-applet command as startup application. Go to Startup Applications and try add dbus-launch nm-applet command as new one. That will fixed the issue. +1 for the Answer.

Comment: Nope, didn't work at all under Gnome-Shell. Received same GtkStatusIcon error.

Comment: Error coming when I tried to test. `dbus-launch nm-applet`  Unable to create /home/satya/.dbus/session-bus
Couldn't exec nm-applet: No such file or directory

Comment: not worked for me. i restarted system too.

Answer (score 9):

This fixed it for me

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
```

Comment: This method worked for me after reboot on ubuntu 15.04

Comment: This worked for me after first uninstalling indiactor-applet-complete, then running this command

Comment: Not worked for me. I restarted the system too.

Comment: not worked for me. i restarted system too.

Answer (score 3):

I also face the same issue network icon is not coming in top bar SO just do the same Open the terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and install and reinstall the network-manager with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome

reboot

nohup nm-applet &
```

Comment: +1 This solved my problem permanently on my Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I changed the file in *~/.config/autostart/nm-applet.desktop*

To this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Network
Comment=Manage your network connections (MATE)
Icon=nm-device-wireless
Exec=dbus-launch nm-applet
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=NetworkManager
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=nm-applet
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nm-applet
Hidden=false
```

Now it shows in Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a while. I tried `sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete` and this did not work. Tried purging and reinstalling gnome network manager which also did not work. Checked through my startup programs and nothing in there was out of place. I tried adding it from the menu on the toolbar and was able to add a network monitor applet but no network indicator that I desired.
Turned out to be a simple fix

> System > Preferences > Look & Feel > Mate Tweak

Selected the 'Traditional' Layout instead of whatever had come with the install and all was well. CAUTION: this will wipe existing applets, so if you have any that you are particularly fond of you will want to back them up. I suggest saving your current layout prior to changing.

If you don't have Mate Tweak then:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install mate-tweak

or https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mate-tweak for a package.

Hope this helps someone.