# Wifi icon not showing signal strength Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: system-tray

The wifi icon in my system tray is just an outline. It doesn't actually show any bars/signal strength.

[image: screenshot]

I've tried using...

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet indicator-network
```

But that didn't work.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Note: I do have a working wireless internet connection.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/507310/network-manager-icon-disappeared-14-04 whether this helps.