# Network/WiFi icon not appearing

Tags: 16.04, networking, icons

Have a problem after i installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Network icon that indicates connection and or WiFi signal on top-right is not appearing. Tried lots of suggestions on site but no luck ( [like here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507310/network-manager-icon-disappeared-14-04) ). Though i can connect to WiFi from network-manager, I prefer the icon handle and the easy it affords.

How can i get this to appear. Thanks.

Comment: if you run these commands in terminal does it have an effect? sudo ifconfig eth0 up then sudo dhclient eth0

Comment: @Graham Device not found.

Comment: Are `nm-applet` and `indicator-application-service` both in the process list? Did you uninstall either `indicator-application` or `network-manager-gnome`?

Comment: @dobey `nm-applet, indicator-application-service`  is not installed. apt install can't locate them either. I have installed `network-manger-gnome`, still no luck.

Comment: @dobey. Okey it's fixed, after a restart prior-to installing the `network-manger-gnome` **Thanks**