# Ubuntu 18.04 ethernet not configuring automatically

Tags: networking, ethernet, configuration, administration

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop installed. The system is eager to configure and operate WiFi, but I need a wired connection because my adapter is slow compared to the 1000BASE-T Ethernet.

Ethernet cable is plugged in, but I see nowhere in the desktop how to configure wired. With WiFi off, there's a "?" next to the volume control. Clicking there shows nothing to do with an Ethernet connection.

On the other hand, if I manually bring the interface up, networking works just fine:

```
% sudo ifup enp5s0f1
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp5s0f1/78:24:af:ca:08:74
Sending on   LPF/enp5s0f1/78:24:af:ca:08:74
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp5s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x637da107)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp5s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x637da107)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.24 on enp5s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7a17d63)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.24 from 192.168.1.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.24 from 192.168.1.1
bound to 192.168.1.24 -- renewal in 41444 seconds.
```

ssh, ftp, web browser... just works.

I've added information that was requested below:

```
% sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 01
       serial: 40:e2:30:ae:5b:17
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-36-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wirele
ss=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
       logical name: enp5s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 78:24:af:ca:08:74
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000
bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=no multicast
=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7814000-f7814fff memory:f7810000-f7813fff
```

Grepping for NetworkManager in syslog:

```
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:24:28 myhostname NetworkManager[802]:   [1539825868.9200] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 40:E2:30:AE:5B:16
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:24:29 myhostname NetworkManager[802]:   [1539825869.1167] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:24:29 myhostname NetworkManager[802]:   [1539825869.1169] device (wlp4s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:24:29 myhostname NetworkManager[802]:   [1539825869.1174] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:24:29 myhostname NetworkManager[802]:   [1539825869.7907] bluez5: NAP: added interface 40:E2:30:AE:5B:16
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.7085] NetworkManager (version 1.10.6) is starting... (for the first time)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.7086] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.7123] manager[0x55ae928e6060]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.7124] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8188] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8189] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "myhostname"
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8192] dns-mgr[0x55ae92900140]: init: dns=systemd-resolved, rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8199] rfkill1: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver ath9k)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8200] manager[0x55ae928e6060]: rfkill: WiFi hardware radio set disabled
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8201] manager[0x55ae928e6060]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname dbus-daemon[775]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=800 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8363] init!
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8364]       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8364]       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8366] guessed connection type (enp5s0f1) = 802-3-ethernet
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8366] update_connection_setting_from_if_block: name:enp5s0f1, type:802-3-ethernet, id:Ifupdown (enp5s0f1), uuid: a4537f7b-6324-fd3f-6489-f76bfb2af0dc
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8367] adding enp5s0f1 to connections
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8367] adding iface enp5s0f1 to eni_ifaces
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8367] management mode: unmanaged
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8371] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0/net/wlp4s0, iface: wlp4s0)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8371] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0/net/wlp4s0, iface: wlp4s0): no ifupdown configuration found.
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8371] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:05:00.1/net/enp5s0f1, iface: enp5s0f1)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8372] locking wired connection setting
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8372] settings-connection[0x55ae928b2360,a4537f7b-6324-fd3f-6489-f76bfb2af0dc]: write: failure to update connection: writing settings not supported
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8372] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8372] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8372] end _init.
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8372] settings: loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list. (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8373] settings: loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2016 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8373] (-1835934528) ... get_connections.
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8373] (-1835934528) ... get_connections (managed=false): return empty list.
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8464] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1 (823e4837-330a-3bf9-8be5-6fc1f1fde418,"Wired connection 1")
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8543] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Necronomicon (b247a602-6c61-4875-af1e-58d0d88bbd81,"Necronomicon")
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8548] get unmanaged devices count: 1
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8548] manager: rfkill: WiFi disabled by radio killswitch; disabled by state file
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8548] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8548] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8549] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'dhclient'
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8550] Loaded device plugin: NMBondDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8550] Loaded device plugin: NMBridgeDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8550] Loaded device plugin: NMDummyDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8550] Loaded device plugin: NMEthernetDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8550] Loaded device plugin: NMInfinibandDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8550] Loaded device plugin: NMIPTunnelDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8550] Loaded device plugin: NMMacsecDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8550] Loaded device plugin: NMMacvlanDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8551] Loaded device plugin: NMPppDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8551] Loaded device plugin: NMTunDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8551] Loaded device plugin: NMVethDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8551] Loaded device plugin: NMVlanDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8551] Loaded device plugin: NMVxlanDeviceFactory (internal)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8570] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8580] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8602] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8611] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8635] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8641] device (lo): carrier: link connected
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8646] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8655] manager: (enp5s0f1): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8663] wifi-nl80211: (wlp4s0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8664] device (wlp4s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8670] manager: (wlp4s0): new 802.11 WiFi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8679] device (wlp4s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8723] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8735] modem-manager: ModemManager available
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8757] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8760] manager: startup complete
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8767] bluez5: NAP: added interface 40:E2:30:AE:5B:16
```

Grepping for enp5s0f1:

```
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname kernel: [    1.210408] r8169 0000:05:00.1 enp5s0f1: renamed from eth0
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8366] guessed connection type (enp5s0f1) = 802-3-ethernet
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8366] update_connection_setting_from_if_block: name:enp5s0f1, type:802-3-ethernet, id:Ifupdown (enp5s0f1), uuid: a4537f7b-6324-fd3f-6489-f76bfb2af0dc
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8367] adding enp5s0f1 to connections
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8367] adding iface enp5s0f1 to eni_ifaces
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8371] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:05:00.1/net/enp5s0f1, iface: enp5s0f1)
/var/log/syslog.1:Oct 17 21:29:46 myhostname NetworkManager[800]:   [1539826186.8655] manager: (enp5s0f1): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
```

Contents of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface enp5s0f1 inet dhcp
```

From /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Thanks for any help,

Charles

Comment: Do you mean 10.04 or 18.04? Please clarify and edit your question as needed. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you running off of a SSD?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the version error. Also, the system is on an SSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>If you're running on a SSD, you run the risk of things  booting faster than the network is coming online and then you'll need to modify the following file: `/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/NetworkManager-wait-online.service`</strike>

```
[Unit]
Description=Network Manager Wait Online
Documentation=man:nm-online(1)
Requires=NetworkManager.service
After=NetworkManager.service
Before=network-online.target
```

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-online -s -q --timeout=**60**
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target

and change the timeout from `30` to `60`. Reboot.

**Update #1:**

- In `terminal`...

`rfkill list`

if this shows any blocked devices...

`rfkill unblock all`

and make sure that no "wireless" hardware switch, or function key, is set to "disabled".

- Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and change...

this:

`iface enp5s0f1 inet dhcp`

to this:

`#iface enp5s0f1 inet dhcp`

- Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and make sure that this line is set to `false`...

`[ifupdown]`

`managed=false`

Reboot the system and retest both wired and wireless connections. Show me `sudo lshw -C network` again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I do have an SSD. Unfortunately, this does not fix the issue. I've been pouring over the dmesg output, and there's no reference to enp5s0f1 except where it says "renamed from eth0"; so, no "link becomes ready" message that I've seen in dmesg output on other systems.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -c network` and `grep -i enp5s0f1 /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i NetworkManager /var/log/syslog*` and `more /etc/network/interfaces` and anything that you find in `/etc/netplan`.

Comment: @crw4096 I almost missed your updates. Make sure to address comments to me starting with "@heynnema". Please see my update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: the answer seemed to be commenting out the line in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

    #iface enp5s0f1 inet dhcp

Commenting this out and rebooting had the Ethernet come up as expected. Removing the comment and the Ethernet inteface does not come up. This seems exactly backwards... @heynnema

Answer (score 0):

All answers I found were solving the problem temporarily but then after reboot it was back to the same. The only thing that fixed it permanently for me was this:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1006979/956940

```
sudo dhclient ens33 # To get back the network temporarily

sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome

reboot

nohup nm-applet &
```

Then click on the diamond icon and select "Enable networking"